# Can't mount TLS certificate into Vault container using only Docker

Tags: docker, ssl, containers, mounted-volumes

I'm new to both **Vault** and **Docker**, I was working with Vault with **Transport Layer Security disabled**, now I want to activate it to be able to **query** Vault over **HTTPS**  I generated **self-signed certificates** using **Openssl** by this command

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 365`

you can find the explanation [Here on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl).

As explained [Hashicorp Vault Discussion](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/hashicorp-vault-error-initializing-listener-of-type-tcp-error-loading-tls-cert-where-is-my-mistake/17533/7) volumes must be mounted from local into the container.

**First**, I have created **docker volume**  and I have **manually** copied the certifications inside that volume

```
docker volume create vault-volume
```

I found in the [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)  that adding `--mount source=vault-volume,target=path_inside_the_container` is likely to help  so here is my command

```
 sudo docker run  --rm  --name hashicorp_vault --mount source=vault-volume,target=/vault/certs \ 
--cap-add=IPC_LOCk -e VAULT_ADDR=http:0.0.0.0:8200 \
 -e 'VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG=$config_placeholder' \
 vault
```

**Configuration placeholder**

```
{
"backend": {
         "file": {
                    "path": "/vault/file"
                   }
           },
         "listener": [{
               "tcp":{
                     "address": "0.0.0.0:8201","tls_disable":"0", 
                     "tls_cert_file":"/vault/certs/cert.pem", 
                     "tls_key_file":"/vault/certs/key.pem"
                     }
           }],
         "api_addr": "http://0.0.0.0:8200",
         "cluster_addr": "https://0.0.0.0:8201",
         "ui": "true"
}
```

Now I got this **error**

```
Error initializing listener of type tcp: error loading TLS cert: open /vault/certs/cert.pem: no such file or directory
```

The container doesn't know about the directory but as I understood that I have mounted it so that it will create it for me

I'm missing things here, I'll appreciate it for you for any helpful **explanation** and a **solution**.